# How can I have bash autocorrect my typos

Tags: bash, autocorrect

I have a silly but very persistent problem. I continually mistype `git grep` as `git grpe`, `gi tgrep` or `gi tgrpe`. Is there a way of telling bash to replace certain strings I type with other strings?

I did find `shopt cdshell` but that seems to be only for directories, and https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck but that seems quite heavy for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

For git you could use bash aliases in combination with git aliases.

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias gi='git'
```

and the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  grpe = grep
  tgrep = grep
  tgrpe = grep
```